# Llenar lista genérica con método en vez de con el constructor

Tags: c#, lista

Estoy intentando cambiar la forma de llenar una lista de objetos genéricos. En vez de hacerlo con el constructor quiero hacerlo con un método. Haciéndolo con el constructor sí me funciona pero al hacer el método y llamarlo no parece funcionar.

**El codigo que me funciona es el siguiente:**

```
 public class Baraja : List<Carta>, IEnumerable<Carta>
{
    private List<Carta> cartas; 

    public Baraja()
    {
        cartas = new List<Carta>(40);
        for (int i = 0; i < cartas.Capacity; i++)
        {
            cartas.Add(new Carta());
        }

    }
 IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }


    public new IEnumerator<Carta> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (Carta c in cartas)
        {
            yield return c;
        }

    }
        public static List<string> NombresImagenes(Baraja baraja)
    {
        List<string> nom = new List<string>();
        foreach(Carta c in baraja)
        {
            nom.Add(c.ToString() + ".png");
        }
        return nom;                
    }
```

**Pero si cambio el constructor por este más el siguiente método:**

```
 public class Baraja : List<Carta>, IEnumerable<Carta>
{
    private List<Carta> cartas; 

    public Baraja()
    {
        cartas = new List<Carta>(40);
    }
public void AnadirCartas()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cartas.Capacity; i++)
        {
            cartas.Add(new Carta());
        }
    }
```

Si lo hago de la primera manera consigo ver los nombres en `Index` sin problemas, pero cambiando al segundo código no me funciona. Entiendo que lo que pasa es que no se llena la lista. No entiendo qué está pasando.

**Modelo `Carta`:**

```
 public enum Palo
{
    oros,
    copas,
    espadas,
    bastos
}
public class Carta
{

    private static int contNum = 1;
    private static int contPalo = 0;

    //public string Cart { get; }
    public int Numero {get; }
    private Palo pal;

    public Carta()
    {
        if (contNum >= 11)
        {
            contNum = 1;
            if (contPalo < 3)
                contPalo++;
            else
                contPalo = 0;
        }
        pal = (Palo)contPalo;
        Numero = contNum;
        contNum++;

        
    }
    public override string ToString() => pal.ToString() + "-" + Numero;
}
}
```

En el `HomeController` tengo lo siguiente:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            Baraja baraja = new Baraja();
            List<string> nombreImagenes = new List<string>();

            baraja.AnadirCartas();
            nombreImagenes = Baraja.NombresImagenes(baraja);
            ViewData["nombreCartas"] = nombreImagenes;

            return View();
        }
```

Y la vista `Index` tiene lo siguiente:

```
<div class="text-center">


    @{
        foreach(var c in ViewData["nombreCartas"] as List<string>)
        {
            var carta = "images/cartas/"+c;
            <p> @carta</p>

        }
    }
```

Comment: no hay nada malo en ese codigo... que error recibis?

Comment: Ninguno. Simplemente no llena la lista con los objetos `Carta` cuando de la otra manera sí lo hacia

Comment: podrias mostrar como es que llamas al metodo AnadirCartas?

Comment: Acabo de editar

Comment: sigue estando bien el codigo.. el problema estara en otro lado?

Comment: No he cambiado nada mas que eso. He probado varias veces a hacerlo y deshacerlo y deja de mostrarmelo en la vista. Reestructuro la pregunta y copio todo el modelo de `Baraja` a ver si ves algo. Gracias

Comment: ese error esta raro, prueba poner cartas = new List<Carta>(40); en el metodo AnadirCartas y no en el constructor como lo tienes

Comment: salvo que no entiendo la necesidad del metodo estatico, yo veo todo bien.. podrias hacer un [mcve] a ver si pasa alguna otra cosa en algun otro lado? deberias ver lo que queres ver sin problemas...

Comment: Creo que ya está todo el código necesario para probarlo. Tienes toda la razón con el apunte del método estático. En cuanto me funcione lo modifico, gracias :)

Comment: Hola @Miguel27 podrías poner unos cuantos puntos de interrupción en tu código para ver si llama al método `AnadirCartas` y si llena la lista como corresponde. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba en otro método de la clase Baraja al que llamaba en el `HomeController`. Seguramente hacia que sí se construyesen los objetos pero que no se se llamase a otros métodos.